# BeanCreationException: No factory method found

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java class which I'm using to instantiate multiple objects for use in test cases.
In my spring configuration for invoking this class I have something like the following:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.foo.MyClass">
   <constructor-arg ref="myBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="myBeanA" factory-bean="myClass" factory-method="getA" />
<bean id="myBeanB" factory-bean="myClass" factory-method="getB" />
<bean id="myBeanC" factory-bean="myClass" factory-method="getC" />
```

MyClass does not extend anything. 
My issue is that calling methods `MyClass.getA()` and `MyClass.getB()` works but `MyClass.getC()` does not and always throws a `BeanCreationException: No factory method found getC()`

None of the methods are static and all of them are public. Debugging through Spring jars I can see that when the bean for `MyClass.getC()` is created it doesn't pick up the method when it does `getLeafMethods()`, but will find methods `getA()` and `getB()` and Object methods but none of the other methods in the class. Has anyone encountered a issue like this before or know why its unable to find all the methods in the class?

I cannot post the actual code but here is simpler version of it:

```
public class MyClass {
        private A a;
        private int i;
        public MyClass(D param) {
           //initialize here
        }

        public A getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public B getB() {
            return new B(i++);
        }

        //I could invoke this in a static way
        //however the same issue occurs either way.
        public C getC() {
            return new C();
        }
}
```

Comment: those methods should be static and public. Post myClass.

Comment: please post the factory code

Comment: Post your MyClass code. getC() may not return bean object...

Comment: Why should the methods be static? I wanted to invoke them as part of an instance as I wanted to do some initialization within the constructor of the class.

Comment: what does the method createMock do exactly?

Comment: Try swapping `return createMock(C.class)` for `return new C();` to confirm if it is related to createMock method, will at least help narrow it down

Comment: createMock creates a MockObject, part of EasyMock jar. It isn't a issue with EasyMock as far I can tell. I've tried returning new C(); as well as creating a new function that just returns new String("asdf"); but it will never recognize any additional methods.

Comment: There really is no point in having myBeanC created by a factory method, if new C() is all that's done in the getC() method. In that case you could just do: <bean id="myBeanC" class="com.foo.C"/>  Maybe the Java compiler does not generate a getC method since it is easily substituted by new C() ... maybe define getC as public C getC() { i++; C result = new C(); i--; return result; } to prove this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there were 2 issues for me, one was a build issue which was cleared with blowing away and recreating my workspace. The second issue was in my case the type C was parametrized, and I needed to specify `new C<T>();` instead of just `new C();`. I was using a static method inside of C `( C.makeC(Params...))` to instantiate the object which I think caused the error. So I guess it was a type erasure issue that caused this.   Thanks for the all the help!

-Niru

Comment: Mark this as the answer to your question!